# How to use custom styled components with ProMotion gem

Tags: rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion and the excellent ProMotion gem.
It all works fine and is super simple, as long as you only want the original Apple design for all components. I've searched high and low for a tutorial on how to using custom-designed elements with a ProMotion gem.

For example:

- How can I style the navigation bar and its buttons and labels?
- How can I style and create custom table rows?

I really want to use ProMotion because it seems like a perfect companion to RubyMotion. It would be cool to see source code for a sample custom-styled app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the ProMotion shout-out, Jonathan. I plan to create a styling guide for ProMotion soon. For now, here are some general guidelines:

- You can use the UIAppearance API to do general styling (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
- Custom table rows are best styled by subclassing `PM::TableViewCell` and adding custom styles to the `layoutSubviews` method. You can mix in `PM::ViewHelper` to get access to `set_attributes:` and `add:` methods.

**Update**

ProMotion style guide: https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/wiki/Guide%3A-Styling-Your-Views

Comment: Perfect! Really looking forward to that guide.